# Permalink structure from two digits to one digit

Tags: customization, permalinks, seo

I moved my website from SquareSpace to wordpress, I exported the content and posts, the post url's are most important in terms of SEO but I have an issue here.

> In wordpress %monthnum% tag is 2 digits so it is adding 0 before
>   single months lets say January to September in wordpress it is 01-09
>   but the same in Squarespace is just 1-9.

This small differnce will impact my SEO because my currently indexed posts are all like this in squarespace

https://www.thejuiceconsultant.com/blog/2018/4/17/how-to-get-over-the-fear-of-starting-your-juice-bar

but the same post is this way in Wordpress

http://741.studio/sajb/blog/2018/04/17/how-to-get-over-the-fear-of-starting-your-juice-bar/

Is there a way in wordpress to make 01-09 to just 1-9, if yes please let me know.

Thanks much

Remove Duplicate on my question the provided answer in linked question doesn't work. I need more inputs from other forum users.

I added this code in my function.php but it didn't work

```
add_filter( 'the_permalink', 't5_strip_leading_zeros_in_url' );
    add_filter( 'month_link', 't5_strip_leading_zeros_in_url' );
add_filter( 'day_link',   't5_strip_leading_zeros_in_url' );

function t5_strip_leading_zeros_in_url( $url )
{
    // no pretty permalinks
    if ( ! $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->get_month_permastruct() )
    {
        return $url;
    }

    return str_replace( '/0', '/', $url );

}
```

also tried this code

```
function remove_leading_zeroes_in_permalink($permalink, $post)
{
    if ($post->post_type == 'post') // change to your post
    {           
        if ('' != $permalink && !in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft')))
        {               
            $permalink = str_replace(array('%monthnum%', '%day%'), array(date('n', strtotime($post->post_date)), date('j', strtotime($post->post_date))), $permalink);
        }
    }
    return $permalink;
}
add_action('post_type_link', 'remove_leading_zeroes_in_permalink', 10, 2); // for custom post types
add_action('post_link', 'remove_leading_zeroes_in_permalink', 10, 2); //for post
```

Both didn't work